# How does the hermitian conjugate of an unitary operator act?

Tags: linear-algebra, physics

I know that $$ A| v \rangle = \sum _n e^{i\alpha n} | n \rangle $$
where $A$ is an unitary operator, and $ \left \{ |n\rangle \right \} $ is an orthonormal complete basis.

In that case, is it true that $$ A^{\dagger}| v \rangle = \sum _n e^{-i\alpha n} | n \rangle$$ ?

If it is true, how can I prove it?

Comment: Where is $v$  on the right side?

Answer (score 2):

$$\langle v| A^{\dagger} = \sum _n e^{-i\alpha_n} \langle n |$$

I don't think that your version is true.

Consider 
$$A= \left[ \matrix {
 0&i\\
 1&0
} \right]$$

$$A^{\dagger}= \left[ \matrix {
 0&1\\
 -i&0
} \right]$$

and apply them to the vector $\left[\matrix{1\\0}\right]$ then express in the standard basis.
$$A \left[\matrix{1\\0}\right] = e^{i ( 0 )}\left[\matrix{0\\1}\right]$$ but
$$A^{\dagger} \left[\matrix{1\\0}\right] = e^{i (- \frac{\pi}{2} )}\left[\matrix{0\\1}\right]$$